# red hat jboss developer studio 11 & 10 doesn't show menu items in mac os x high sierra

Tags: eclipse, macos, macos-high-sierra, jboss-developer-studio

Last week I successfully update my MacBook to High Sierra, the new OS of Apple...

I decided to also update my developer studio. I upgraded from 10 to 11. No problem so far.

I was starting to develop in version 11, when I needed a menu item. For instance Project > Clean...

ALL those menu items in the top level window menu of developer studio are greyed out... My conclusion was that version 11 is not compatible with the high sierra.

I switched back to 10... DAMN! Same issue. Installed 10 and 11, with and without the current workspace. Same issue!

I guess it is due to the fact that it is due to high sierra. I cannot revert my mac, so using developer studio at this moment on my MacBook is very problematic.

Who else?

@Jboss developers: when will this be fixed? Or how do I have to create a bug report? The menu in developer studio to report a bug is disabled...

Looked on google but no one has reported this so far... or Google hasn't picked it up yet ;)

Comment: If your system language is not English look at [this](https://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170925criticalbug.php)

Comment: The workaround in your link works @greg-449. Thanks! However, I specifically used the jboss-developer-studio tag in the hope their developers pick it up and can tell me a release date of the next developer studio which will have this fixed..

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of the problem, and this may land in the next update release